# Remote Database Access

Tags: php, objective-c, xcode

I need to access a remote database from my iPhone. I have an account on iPage, but as far as i know it does not support remoteMySql. I wrote a php script that will connect to the remote database. Currently i run it on localhost and this makes it of no use on the phone. Can someone tell me what is the best solution to my problem. Is there a way to use remote access on iPage, the database is on another server not iPage. Or can i write an api or something that will run on iPage ? The best thing would be if i can find a free webpage that can host my php script. Had one but its not working anymore. Any suggestions ?

```
<?php
$username = "qqqq";
$password = "qqqq";
$hostname = "qqq.qqq.qqq.qqq"; 

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db("ttbus",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select examples");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT stations.name, stations.lon, stations.lat, station_display_rows.minutesToArrival,routes.number FROM stations,station_display_rows,routes WHERE stations.id = station_display_rows.stationId AND routes.routeId = station_display_rows.routeId");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<h1>";
 echo $row{'name'}."<h2>";
   echo $row{'lon'}."<h3>";
   echo $row{'lat'}."<h4>";
   echo $row{'minutesToArrival'}."<p>";  
   echo $row{'number'};
}

mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Comment: there are no mysql drivers for ios. at best your idevice can use http requests to talk to a webservice, and that service does the mysql stuff and returns results.

Comment: but can those services access remote mysql basses since i have no way to upload script on the mysql server ?

Comment: yes, as long as the network and user permissions for the mysql accounts are configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with iPage, but if you want to access data from a web site, then you should create a REST endpoint that will return your data in JSON format. Your iOS app will then make this connection, grab the data and you can use it in your app. You can store this data in a a local database using Core Data, save it as a file or just use it in memory.

If you need help creating the REST endpoints in PHP, that should be directed to the PHP section or search for some tutorials, there are plenty.

To read the data from your iOS app, you should read this tutorial: [NSUrlSession Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial) DON'T try and use AFNetworking, its overkill for what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in shared hosting platform, remote MySQL is not supported in it. It is supported in their VPS/Dedi platform.